# Group By to find differences between elements of table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with items indices, scores and years. I would like to count each incident where a person's score went up between two years (table is sorted by date), so that for the following table:

```
person_index   score   year
3              76      2003
3              86      2004
3              86      2005
3              87      2006
4              55      2005
4              91      2006
```

I will get an output of person with index 3 with 2 changes, and person 4 with 1 change:

```
person_index   times_changed
3              2
4              1
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: And what about missing years?  Such as 2006 for person 3?

Comment: to add to @GordonLinoff 's comment or missing 2005 year for person 4 for that matter.

Comment: To simplify I edited so that all years are consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table by itself on the condition *a person's score went up between two years*:

```
select 
  t.person_index,  
  count(*) times_changed
from tablename t
inner join tablename tt
on t.person_index = tt.person_index
and tt.year - t.year = 2
and tt.score > t.score
group by t.person_index
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jeQkHyUvUsoPSbw2XuD26J/0)

Comment: `times_changed` is the counter of the rows returned by the groupping. The rows are groupped by these conditions: tt.year - t.year = 2 (must be exactly 2 years difference) and tt.score > t.score (the score increased).

Comment: . . Wow.  That is definitely not how I interpreted the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need the previous value.  One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select person_id,
       sum( score > prev_score ) as times_changed
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.score
              from t t2
              where t2.person_index = t.person_index and
                    t2.year < t.year
              order by t2.year desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_score
      from t
     ) t
group by person_id;
```

Note that this version will return persons with `0` changes.